# No Internet Connection when Bluetooth is active (Intel Advanced-N 6230, Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, wireless, bluetooth, intel

When being connected to a WiFi-network, everything is fine when Bluetooth is disabled.
When Bluetooth is enabled, but not connected, 30 ping packets are lost during the toggling.
When Bluetooth is enabled and connected to a device, there is no internet connection anymore and every ping packet has the following output (e.g):

```
From www.zeit.de (217.13.68.220) icmp_seq=110 Destination Host Unreachable
From www.zeit.de (217.13.68.220) icmp_seq=111 Destination Host Unreachable
From www.zeit.de (217.13.68.220) icmp_seq=112 Destination Host Unreachable
```

When disabling Bluetooth again, internet resumes working as usual.

Additional info:

Wireless-n is disabled having used this command:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

Output of wireless-info All-In-One script:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=6zr0XQpu

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need also to disable bluetooth coexistence feature. Run

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 bt_coex_active=0"
```

That should fix the problem after reboot.

[Bluetooth coexistence](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/Bluetooth-coexistence/) feature in `iwlwifi` is overdone. When enabled it makes wireless connection slow or unusable in many cases. This is a kernel bug that should be reported.

Comment: Wow, just 2 minutes after asking the question. You are what makes the Linux community the best in the world!